# Screenshot for in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a very simple question.

Can I change screenshot for in-app purchase, when the status of my app is "Waiting for review"?

P.S: When I created new in-app purchase, I have attached to it wrong screenshot and forgot about it. Now my app is waiting for review and I can not change this screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the "screenshot for review" that Apple require for submitting an in-app purchase don't worry: it is never used! It's a poor-design implementation, if like a flag "ok, you can review it now".
SO don't worry and good luck with your app ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope it really so.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. How did it work out for you?

Comment: Cristi, yes, everything was ok.